# Video.js - Why need both npm module and <script> tag?

Tags: reactjs, npm, video.js

According to the official Video.js documentation (http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html), you add the script tags for the js and css to your page. Then, you install the package manager via npm or bower.

Why do you need both of these?

I would think it's either one of the other. So I tried just using the npm package. My React class looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';

export default class MyVideoContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
        <video id="test_video_1" className="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" >
          <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <p className="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
        </video>
      </div>;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    videojs("test_video_1", {}, function(){

    });
  }

}
```

The javascript appears to load correctly, but no CSS gets applied to the video, so it looks like pure garbage. There are a bunch of form buttons underneath the video for Play and Pause, and all kinds of crazy stats.

But it works better if I just use  tags with no videojs import.

I would prefer to use the npm module, but can't get the CSS to work correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `Video.js` docs says you need npm and also the css to run `video.js` properly on your system. The npm package only contains the javascript that needs to be used in order to run your `video.js` in react but doesn't contain the css. So a separate file that contains the css needs to be specified along with importing it in your `React component`. Mention this in your `index.html` and you will see the styles loading properly

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Interesting, that worked. But if I look in the node_modules/video.js/src/css/ there are a ton of css files. Why don't these just work? Shouldn't they get bundled by webpack? Or is my understanding of the workflow incorrect?

Comment: You need a style loader setup in webpack to import the css, rather than set up a link href as in the example above. Once you have your webpack environment setup to handle/load css as well, you can simply put:

@require "../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.css";

in your css file.

Comment: IMO, you only need the NPM module if you intend to modify the Video.js source. Otherwise, you may as well either load it from a CDN or self-host a copy that you download from either a CDN or the /dist directory on the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack, you could try also *ProvidePlugin* option, from
https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record/issues/123#issuecomment-282522353

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    videojs: "video.js",
    "window.videojs": "video.js"
}),`